# Model with good results suffers of overfitting?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I'm now creating a machine learning model. This is the code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(12, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(4, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100,validation_split = 0.33 )

model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
metrics_train = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
metrics_test = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

The results on train set e test set are:

```
Train Set - loss, accuracy:  [0.04302208498120308, 0.9875252842903137]
Test Set - loss, accuracy:  [0.07550123333930969, 0.981918215751648]
```

I know that the overfitting occurs when a model is too specific. Particularly when the testing error (loss) is a way **worse** then training error.
In my case, the differences in loss are minimum.
I was trying to make a plot of history to see graphically how the model is going but it is a total mess (seems obviously overfitting).
This is my plot code:

```
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[This is the plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDxX8.png)

Now I am very confused. Theoretically, my model isn't suffering of overfitting but graphically there's overfitting. Am I wrong? Can you help me please?

Comment: What causes you to believe there's overfitting? Going from 98.75% accuracy (`train` set) to 98.19% accuracy (`test` set) seems not bad?

Comment: Agree with @JoshuaVoskamp that there is not huge difference between the results for training and test data set. If there is then you have to see how are you choosing the training set ( e.g is it random). Is the distribution of training set uniform enough ? So you could check all of this with more machine learning :)

Comment: Honestly, for me it's not overfitting. I've got doubts because of the plot. That's a mess and it doesn't seem to be just right...

Answer (score 0):

I think this would not be considered to be overfitting. Your model is still 98% accurate for validation data. Difference of around 1% with validation data would be acceptable for any model.

I would consider overfitting if accuracy difference is atleast more than 5% to 10% depending on the use case. Further you can try increasing the split ratio if that would impact overall accuracy.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused because of the plot. For me, the model isn't suffering of overfitting.

Comment: You should not look at the plot only but also analyze the numbers as plot's meaning can change with axes range.